# RegEx Whitespace Reduction + Textarea Exclusion

Tags: html, regex, textarea

I'm using `/\s+/` to reduce all whitespace characters to one (in every group). This is currently used to minify HTML, however textareas need the extra line breaks which are otherwise filtered. How can this regex be modified as to ignore the line breaks inside `<textarea></textarea>` tags?

Also, a textarea might have properties such as `id` or `class`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you define your whole document as being an alternation of non-textareas and textareas, alternating ?

Comment: @RobW I'd argue that HTML minimization doesn't have to be done at all, but unfortunately this is a client requirement. I tried to find a `lightweight` method, and here I am.

Comment: Can't you just turn on gzip compression of HTML content and be done with it?

Comment: @Eregrith I've considered that idea but I prefer to make the implementation as light as possible. If this can't be done with RegEx, I'll try your solution.

Comment: @Joey Already implemented. This doesn't seem to be the reason for the minification however. The client apparently wants to make the code `unreadable`, no matter how much I stress that minification will only pose a minor annoyance to a decoder.

Comment: If they want unreadable you should probably replace the whole HTML by Javascript creating the DOM tree element by element. And then use character references for any text that is used. That's quite the inverse of minification, though ;-). Still, idiotic requirements call for idiotic measures, I'd say

Comment: Aren't you asking for a regex which can see balanced parenthesis (which is impossible)? I think you need an (xml) parser/other tool to do this.

Comment: Have you tried this google search? http://www.google.de/search?q=obfuscate+html

Comment: @ChrisSmith I meant from inside the regexp. Like `((nontextarea-capture-spaces-and-replace-with-one)*(textarea-do-not-touch)*)*`

Comment: @Eregrith Good idea. Unfortunately the amount and type of the segments is variable :(

Comment: @ChrisSmith What programming language is to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a generic solution in PHP, hope it'll be pretty easy to rewrite in any language you use for this task.

```
$raw = '
  My   line   is   here <textarea>And 
there</textarea> there   and everywhere';

$chunks = preg_split('#(<textarea>.+?</textarea>)#si', 
  $raw, null, 
  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // -- 1

$chunks_length = count($chunks);
for ($index = 0; 
     $index < $chunks_length; 
     $index += 2) { // -- 2
  $chunks[$index] = preg_replace('#(\s)+#', '$1', $chunks[$index]); // -- 3
}

var_dump(implode('', $chunks));
// My line is here <textarea>And 
// there</textarea> there and everywhere
```

This is what happens here: with the `--1` line we split your text into array of fragments. Elements of this array with odd indexes [1, 3, ...] would actually be the 'textarea' chunks, as we set `preg_split` to work in 'delimiter-capturing' mode. The point is that we won't process them (with stepping over them in `for` loop), and will compress the whitespace only (`--3`) for 'content' elements.

Still, this approach is very fragile, as Rob W rightly mentioned: not all whitespace in HTML can be easily compressed.

P.S. `s` modifier in regex used for a reason; otherwise `.+?` pattern will fail to capture ending `\n` symbol (preventing to capture properly multiline chunks).

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `/(?:\s+(?![^<]*<\/textarea>)|[^\S\n\r]+)/` with case insensitivity modifier.